# Function that does something and calls a built-in function that deletes it

Tags: python, class, oop, del

I'm building a task manager and I want to use a complete-func that's going to do something with the instantiated and then call `del` and delete the instantiated class object. Is it possible? I'm trying hard to find a solution.

Tried to use a function from the class, and tried to find articles about this subject, but no success.

```
from datetime import date

class reg_task:
    def __init__(self, what_to_do, date=date.today(), hour=None, tag=None, project="day to day task", priority=None, remind_time=None):
        self.what_to_do = what_to_do
        self.date = date
        self.hour = hour
        self.tag = tag
        self.project = project
        self.priority = priority
        self.remind_time = remind_time

    def __str__(self):
        return f'task {self.what_to_do}, to-do-date - {self.date}'

    def tasks_complete(self):
        with open(r"C:\Users\Avi Fenesh\Desktop\python\tasks_project\archive\archive", "a") as archive:
            archive.write(f"{str(self)} \n")
        del self
```

The problem is with `tasks_complete()`. When I call the function it doesn't delete the instantiated class object.

Comment: Is there some other container somewhere that holds the task instances? Where are you trying to delete the instance *from*?

Comment: no, i tried a simple example. saved an instance and then tried to delete him immediately.

Comment: How can you tell the object wasn't deleted?

Comment: id try to call him again in the interpeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because objects can't be garbage collected as long as someone holds a reference to them. Simply doing `del self` is not enough.

See: [del self vs self.__del__() - and what is the proper way to cleanup in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765687/del-self-vs-self-del-and-what-is-the-proper-way-to-cleanup-in-python)

Comment: so there is another way to do it and to make sure that the instance is not exist anymore?

Comment: The instance will automatically be removed once there are no references to it. In general unless you have a very specific reason for it, you should let garbage collection handle such things for you.

Comment: but my idea is immediately remove the instance. i gonna use a func that gonna show all the task that connected to the current day, and i want that instance that i marked as complete won't appear

Comment: In that case it would be more straightforward to remove the task from whatever data structure you're using to store the tasks, or to mark it as complete or something, so that when you display tasks you don't display it.

Comment: If you do `a = reg_task()` and then the instance deleted itself, what would you expect to happen to the following code that tries to use `a`?